# Wifi connect but no internet access

Tags: adb

This is a strange thing that started happening with the wifi network at my work. Android devices connected to the network say "Connected, no internet access " however the internet works perfectly well.This has happened to devices running Qualcomm 8909 android 8.1.0 but the issue is only can’t download any app through playstore so please require urgent help if can solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have had that same issue and that was because my IPv6 was turned off and so the other device that was using my hotspot was unable to access the internet. So check your settings and if they will check theirs.